# abstract simplicity results for anisotropic quasi-simple algebraic groups defined over a non-archimedean local field

Tags: algebraic-groups

I was wondering if anyone has some references I can look at that deal with results that identify some abstractly quasi-simple normal subgroup of the group of rational points of an anistropic absolutely quasi-simple algebraic group defined over a non-archimedean local field. I have had a look at Jacques Tits' article "Algebraic and abstract simple groups", and he mentioned the existence of such results in general, but I'm particularly interested in sources that deal with the case where the ground field is a non-archimedean local field of positive characteristic. Would the Borel-Tits article "Groupes reductifs" be a useful source?

Comment: The Borel-Tits theory doesn't address this kind of question, but instead develops general structure and classification theorems for isotropic groups.   The anisotropic case is much more open-ended and depends essentially on the fields involved.   For this you need to look instead at the extensive literature ranging from Dieudonne to G. Prasad and A. Rapinchuk, etc.  The recent book by Conrad-Gabber-Prasad would help to provide the modern framework.

Comment: If $K$ is a (locally compact, non-archimedean) local field and $G$ is an anisotropic nontrivial semisimple $K$-group, then $G(K)$ is an infinite profinite group and hence is residually finite, not simple, not even virtually simple.